# How to mock a javax.mail.Address?

Tags: java, mocking

```
import javax.mail.Address;

public class MockAddress extends Address{

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ?;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ?;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object address) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ?;
    }

}
```

Where I need add some code to change email on my fake email?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you mock it? It's a simple data object - don't mock it, just pass in an appropriate one for testing. (EDIT: For example, you could easily use `InternetAddress`.)

You should be mocking dependencies which provide a *service* - don't bother mocking things like simple collections, data types like `Address` etc. By all means mock the thing which is *giving* you an address, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Because it is an abstract class and I don't can extends it. But I need pass to this class my own address for testing. How I can do it?

Comment: @matemink: Any reason not to use `InternetAddress` as a simple implementation?

Comment: besides, if there really were something to mock, why not use one of the great mocking frameworks available.  I haven't hand-written a mock in years now.